# How can I go to end of parenthesis/brackets/quotes without switching insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a plugin that makes you get out of parenthesis/brackets/quotes/etc when you're inside them. I find it kind of hard having to ESC to command mode and typing A to get out of the parenthesis to go to the end of the line in Insert mode, is there a plugin that meets my needs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A plugin would be overkill. Add this mapping to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>A
```

- `<C-o>` is used to issue a *normal* mode command without leaving *insert* mode.
- `A`, well… you know what it does.

Comment: I'm trying to use the commands from this page http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_Parenthesis_And_Brackets_Handling_Easier but I can't get them to work

Comment: No need for a new mapping to go to the end of the line. On descent keyboards, just press `<end>`.

Comment: @sidyll, why not? `<C-a>` and `<C-e>` already work in Vim's command line. Actually I'm so used to it that I didn't even think about `<End>`. Stupid me.

Comment: @romainl I know, that was just an infamous joke. About `<End>`, well I find it harder than `<C-O>A` which in my opinion is yet harder than `<esc>A`, but you might want to consider the fact that my esc is in place of my caps lock key.

Comment: OK, I know it is not cool to chime in here and say 'THANKS', but I don't care. I have been searching for this my entire life. You have saved me from the forever annoying '<Esc>A'

Comment: @romainl This doesn't work for `(hello everyone) I am going....`. When I cursor in inside the `()` your solution move cursor to the end of the line without placing the cursor before `I am going...`.

Comment: @alhelal My answer addresses the question as asked. If you have a different problem ask a different queston.

Answer (score 5):

If you install the [delimitMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) you can achieve this with the `<S-e>` or `<C-g>g` mapping.

Comment: Have been using delimitMate for months, now I know this trick, thank you

Comment: These days `<S-Tab>` will jump over a single closing delimiter or quote, `<C-G>g` will jump
over contiguous delimiters and/or quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm use to using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump out of things like parenthesis, curly braces, etc., so I just made a simple mapping to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> that simply moves the character 1 character to the right from INSERT mode. Here's my simple mapping that seems to be just fine for my purposes.

```
inoremap <S-Tab> <esc>la
```

Edit: It seems that delimitMate has this same mapping (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) for jumping over a closing delimiter. I think i'll just use that since I already use delimitMate.

Answer (score 3):

Since I use [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) plugin, I have changed its default `g:AutoPairsShortcutJump` option

```
" Jump outside '"({
if !exists('g:AutoPairsShortcutJump')
  let g:AutoPairsShortcutJump = '<C-l>'
endif
```

Now it's easy not only to jump ouside pairs but also insert them.

Answer (score 2):

Native vim command without remapping:

```
Alt + Shift + a
```

- `Shift + a`: that's `A`ppend.
- `Alt`: to execute a normal mode command in insert mode without leaving the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I remapped `alt-h,j,k,l` to move the cursor without having to reach for the arrow keys. So it's just `<m-l>` to jump over a single parenthesis. I also have `<C-a>` and `<C-e>` to go to the beginning and end of line, and `<C-h>` and `<C-l>` to jump a word left or right:

```
"  alt-h,j,k,l  move cursor left,down,up,right
inoremap <m-h> <Left>
inoremap <m-j> <Down>
inoremap <m-k> <Up>
inoremap <m-l> <Right>
"  ^a and ^e move cursor to begin and end of line
inoremap <C-a> <C-o>I
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>A
"  ^h and ^l move cursor 1 word left and right
inoremap <C-h> <C-o>b
inoremap <C-l> <Esc>ea
```