# Step Over Bracket, Parenthesis etc with Tab in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'd like to be able to hit tab and have it step over/move outside the closing tag in Vim. [I can kind of achieve this by adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037825/vim-get-out-of-parenthesis-brackets-etc)

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>A
```

to my .vimrc, but this only works by hitting Ctrl+e (and it moves to the end of line, not outside the closing marker). I'd prefer to use tab.

I had this set up in Sublime Text 2 by using:

```
[
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[;=><',)\"\\]]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote this little vimscript that I think does what you want to do. Hope it helps

```
if !exists( "g:out_of_expression_quick_key" )
    let g:out_of_expression_quick_key = "<Tab>"
endif

execute "imap " . g:out_of_expression_quick_key . " <C-r>=IncreaseColNumber()<CR>"
execute "imap " . g:out_of_expression_quick_key[0] . 'S-' . g:out_of_expression_quick_key[1:] . ' <C-r>=DecreaseColNumber()<CR>'

let s:delimiters_exp = '[\[\]{}())"' . "'" . '<>]'

fun! IncreaseColNumber()
    let l:colnum = col('.')
    let l:line = getline('.')
    if l:line[col('.') - 1:l:colnum] =~# s:delimiters_exp
        return "\<Right>"
    endif
    if g:out_of_expression_quick_key =~# "<Return>"
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
    if g:out_of_expression_quick_key =~# "<Tab>"
        return "\<Tab>"
    endif
endfunction

fun! DecreaseColNumber()
    let l:line = getline('.')
    if l:line[col('.') - 2] =~# s:delimiters_exp
        return "\<Left>"
    endif
    if g:out_of_expression_quick_key =~# "<Return>"
        return "\<S-CR>"
    endif
    if g:out_of_expression_quick_key =~# "<Tab>"
        return "\<S-Tab>"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
<Esc>va(<Esc>`<
```

that puts the cursor on previous "(" character matched after current position ?

"<", instead of the last ">", will put cursor on next unmatched ")" ... "(" can be replaced by "{" or "[" or "s" (sentences) or "p" (paragraphs) or """ (strings). More possibilities are shown by:

```
:help a(
```

To go at end of current paragraph, you also have:

```
<C-o>}
```

Replace "}" by ")" to go at end of current sentence.

To go at end of next () or {} or [], you can type

```
<C-o>%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I'm going to leave the other answer as correct in the vein of "if it ain't broke don't fix it".